# access the element using selenium from label

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following html code

```
<label class="error" id="field">Invalid format </label>
```

I am trying to get the value **Invalid format** using the following command :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("field")).getText());
```

but it returns nothing.

Please let me know the code to get the value **Invalid format** using selenium

Comment: HTML code is <label id="field" class="error">Invalid format </label>

Comment: you can put your html code with question.

Comment: Does your id="field" is unique? and is always visible when page load?

Comment: yes the id field is unique and is always visible

Comment: HTML code is <label id="field" class="error">Invalid format </label>

Comment: I would get that element like you are doing using the Id, if the ID is unique. If it is not then I would look at an alternative way to identify the Element (an ID should always be unique). So, is the ID unique?

Comment: yes the id is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your label is visible already , Please use below code to get text :

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field']")).getText());
```

Comment: It returned the "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"

Comment: I wrote the code as System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field']")).getText());    it returned nothing

Comment: then I am sure label is not visible when code search for it. can you please tell in which site you are doing? so I can check.

Comment: it is able to access the label as : System.out.println("result is " +driver.findElement(By.id("field")).getAttribute("class"));       returns error as result as expected  and System.out.println("result is " +driver.findElement(By.id("field")).getAttribute("id"));  returns field as expected      u cannot be able to access the site as it is internal to me

Comment: Then it must find label text also. see my updated answer. I have added wait. use that please.

Comment: Thanks a lot... problem was with wait ...please modify the code as System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field']")).getText());    worked  as id is "field" not "error"